# How to interpolate between two `ThemeData` classes

Tags: flutter, dart

According to documentation it is easy to linearly interpolate between two colors(anyone who is interested will easily find a solution with docs or SO) , and even more it is possible to recursively interpolate to create a smooth transition even a hole class, like `ThemeData`.

*How this can be achieved (at least the idea)?*

Purpose of this to create smooth  light-dark theme interpolation.

Comment: Kindly Add the link you mentioned as doc and share what you have done up to now please

Comment: @Alperen this can be googled in a second https://flutter.dev/docs/resources/inside-flutter, what code you expect? Setting interpolation between two values? He is saying he knows how to do it and asks how to do this with class.

Comment: @SimonSot Thanks for your a second

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ThemeData class has a .lerp method.  Always look there first:

```
var mediumTheme = ThemeData.lerp(oneTheme, otherTheme, between0and1);
```